# Why Calendar in Android return date 31 June?

Tags: android, calendar

I set

```
Calendar kal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and cause:

```
kal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, + 58);
kal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, + 58);
kal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, + 58);
....
```

and I get eg. 31 June. Why ? Though June don't have 31 days.

Full code:

```
day = dpicker.getDayOfMonth();
        month = dpicker.getMonth()+1;
        year = dpicker.getYear();
        tpicker.clearFocus();
        tpicker.setIs24HourView(true);
        hour = tpicker.getCurrentHour();
        minute = tpicker.getCurrentMinute();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, minute);

Calendar kal = calendar;
kal.add(...);

    datka = String.format("%02d/%02d", kal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), kal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

And data returns 31/06.

When I write `month = dpicker.getMonth();` I get 01/06

Comment: remember that months for java.util.Calendar are 0 based. JUNE is 5 not 6

Comment: How do you got 31 June? Can you show your code?

Comment: Post your code what you have done exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Calendar.MONTH` is zero-based and July (the index 6 month) has 31 days.